# Getting error: Cannot resolve method 'makeText' in Android

Tags: android, android-afilechooser

I am a newbie.
Getting error:

> Cannot resolve method 'makeText'

I am using navigation drawer and My class name is `MainFragment.java`.
Actually I was to trying to use File and Folder Explorer, only this error.

What I have tried: Tried using `MainFragment.getContext()` and `getActivity()` and `context` and `this`, in-place of `MainFragment.this` but none is working.

MainFragment.java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment
{
    //Defined for file edittext.
    EditText editText2;

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /*  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        }
    */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        Button dirChooserButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.skipButton);       //Browse Button
        dirChooserButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            private String m_chosenDir = "";
            private boolean m_newFolderEnabled = true;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // Create DirectoryChooserDialog and register a callback
                DirectoryChooserDialog directoryChooserDialog =
                        new DirectoryChooserDialog(MainFragment.this,
                                new DirectoryChooserDialog.ChosenDirectoryListener()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                   public void onChosenDir(String chosenDir)
                                    {
                                        m_chosenDir = chosenDir;
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                getActivity(), "Chosen directory: " +
                                                        chosenDir, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });
                // Toggle new folder button enabling
                directoryChooserDialog.setNewFolderEnabled(m_newFolderEnabled);
                // Load directory chooser dialog for initial 'm_chosenDir' directory.
                // The registered callback will be called upon final directory selection.
                directoryChooserDialog.chooseDirectory(m_chosenDir);
                m_newFolderEnabled = ! m_newFolderEnabled;
            }
        });

        @Override
        public void onChosenDir(String chosenDir)
        {
            m_chosenDir = chosenDir;
            Toast.makeText(MainFragment.this, "Chosen  directory: " +chosenDir,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }   
}
```

[DirectoryChooserDialog.java](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x72D21rB9dUGpSRUlfZFBoV2c)

Actually I tried this link for making File and Folder Chooser: [link to the webpage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/547636/Android-Ready-to-use-simple-directory-chooser-dial)

Comment: If you can add the whole class from which this snippet is copied, it would help us find the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Fragment will not be able to show your toast, it has to come from activity. Try the following:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Chosen directory: " + chosenDir, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: @Bati: For example, see [this sample code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Internet/Download/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/downmgr/DownloadFragment.java#L117-L118).

Comment: Dialog ChooserDialog(Android.content.Context, ChosenDirectoryListener) in DirectoryChooserDialog can not be applied to (com.threefriends.filecrypto.MainFragment, ChosenDirectoryListener).                           After replacing it with MainFragment.this

Answer (score 0):

try this one
Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this,"Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Here Mainactivity is the name of class